# check if there are duplicate values in 2 datagridview

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare the rows and columns with 2 datagridview. The first column s1 in (DGV1) has found the duplicate values in s1 (DGV2). The second column  s2  in (DGV1) is mismatched with the second column  s2  in (DGV2). What's wrong with the code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount ; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount; j++)
       {
         if ( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == 
              dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            { 
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = 
               Color.Yellow;
               dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = 
               Color.YellowGreen;
            }
       }     
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClLmk.jpg)

Comment: Your algorithm never prove the second column. Actually it proofs the first column only. To get the values of the second column you must change `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` with `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()`. Or better: loop also though all columns with a for-loop over `dataGridView1.ColumnCount`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount ; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount; j++)
       {
         if ( (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == 
               dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) &&
              (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == 
               dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) )

            { 
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = 
               Color.Yellow;
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = 
               Color.Yellow;
               dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = 
               Color.YellowGreen;
               dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = 
               Color.YellowGreen;
            }
       }     
  }
```

Comment: Is not working either. Thanks for your efforts, Dhanushka, but the problem is still present...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in table1.Rows) //LOOP ROWS TABLE 1
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell1 in row1.Cells) //LOOP COLUMNS TABLE 1
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row2 in table2.Rows) //LOOP ROWS TABLE 2
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell2 in row2.Cells) //LOOP COLUMNS TABLE 2
            {
                if (cell1.Value != null && cell2.Value != null&& cell2.Value.ToString() == cell1.Value.ToString())
                {
                    cell1.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    cell2.Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hey Marcel16, this should solve your problem:

[image]

Comment: this works especially well, Mar Tin!! your algorithm is based on 2 rows and 2 columns. i once permitted myself to increase the rows in DGV2, but an error occurs if a row series added to DGV2. however i would like to thank you for your work and support!